# Problema ao exibir o resultado com meu código no blogger

Tags: javascript, html

Yo Galera, beleza! Estou com um pequeno problema. Eu fiz um código para que fosse exibido no na página do meu blog um gerador de Link Me. No qual a pessoa preenche o formulário  e no final é gerado o código para a pessoa copiar e colar no blog dela. Mas na hora de clicar no botão e gerar o código, nada aparece no caixa onde deveria. Será que é um erro no meu código? (Ele está logo abaixo.) Agradeço a ajuda!

```
<h2 style="text-align: center;">
<span style="color: #3d85c6;">
Formulário</span></h2>
<br />
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="text-align: left; width: 580px;"><tbody>
<tr>
      <td width="225">Endereço do Blog<span style="color: red;">*</span></td>
      <td width="355"><input id="urlblog" size="60" type="text" value="http://amefuriblog.blogspot.com" /></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
      <td width="225">Link da Imagem<span style="color: red;">*</span></td>
      <td width="355"><input id="urlimg" size="60" type="text" value="http://i58.tinypic.com/amefuriblog.png" /></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
      <td width="225">Título do Blog</td>
      <td width="355"><input id="titulo" size="60" type="text" value="Amefuri Blog" /></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
      <td width="225">Descrição do Blog</td>
      <td width="355"><input id="descricao" size="60" type="text" value="Seu blog favorito de Cultura Japonesa!" /></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
      <td width="225">Largura Imagem</td>
      <td width="355"><input id="larguraimg" size="3" type="text" value="120" /> pixels</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
      <td width="225">Altura Imagem</td>
      <td width="355"><input id="alturaimg" size="3" type="text" value="60" /> pixels</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
      <td width="225">Largura Caixa de Código</td>
      <td width="355"><input id="larguracaixa" size="3" type="text" value="200" /> pixels</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
      <td width="225">Altura Caixa de Código</td>
      <td width="355"><input id="alturacaixa" size="3" type="text" value="60" /> pixels</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
<div style="text-align: left;">
<br /></div>
<div style="text-align: left;">
<input class="gerarcodigo" type="button" value="Gerar Código" />
</div>
<div style="text-align: left;">
<span style="color: red;"><span style="font-weight: normal;"><br /></span></span></div>
<div style="text-align: left;">
<span style="color: red; font-size: x-small;"><span style="font-weight: normal;">*Campos Obrigatórios</span></span></div>
<h3 style="text-align: center;">
<span style="color: #3d85c6;">
Código do seu Gadget está abaixo!</span></h3>
<div style="text-align: center;">
<textarea name="resultado" onfocus="this.select()" onmouseover="this.focus()" style="height: 200px; margin: 2px; width: 580px;"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
var titulo       = document.getElementById("titulo");
var descricao    = document.getElementById("descricao");
var urlblog      = document.getElementById("urlblog");
var urlimg       = document.getElementById("urlimg");
var larguraimg   = document.getElementById("larguraimg");
var alturaimg    = document.getElementById("alturaimg");
var larguracaixa = document.getElementById("larguracaixa");
var alturacaixa  = document.getElementById("alturacaixa");
var botao        = document.getElementsByClassName("gerarcodigo")[0];
var caixa        = document.getElementsByName("resultado")[0];
var inicio       = "<div align=&quot;center&quot;>
"
var fim          = "&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;</textarea></div>
"

botao.onclick = function() {
  if (larguracaixa == "")
    {larguracaixa = 200}
  if (alturacaixa == "")
    {alturacaixa = 60}
  if (larguraimg == "")
    {codlagura = "";
     codlaguraparse = ""}
  else
    {codlargura = "width=&quot;" + larguraimg.value + "&quot;";
     codlarguraparse = "width=&amp;quot;" + larguraimg.value + "&amp;quot;"}
  if (alturaimg == "")
    {codaltura = "";
     codalturaparse = ""}
  else
    {codaltura = "height=&quot;" + alturaimg.value + "&quot;";
     codalturaparse = "height=&amp;quot;" + alturaimg.value + "&amp;quot;"}
  imagem       = "<img alt=&quot;" + titulo.value + " - " + descricao.value + "&quot; title=&quot;" + titulo.value + " - " + descricao.value + "&quot; src=&quot;" + urlimg.value + "&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; " + codlargura + " " + codaltura + "/>"
  caixacod     = "<br/><textarea onfocus=&quot;this.select()&quot; style=&quot;margin: 2px; width: " + larguracaixa.value + "px; height: " + alturacaixa.value + "px&quot; onmouseover=&quot;this.focus()&quot; name=&quot;textarea&quot;>"
  linkparse    = "&amp;lt;a href=&amp;quot;" + urlblog.value + "&amp;quot; target=&amp;quot;_blank&amp;quot;&amp;gt;"
  imagemparse  = "&amp;lt;img alt=&amp;quot;" + titulo.value + " - " + descricao.value + "&amp;quot; title=&amp;quot;" + titulo.value + " - " + descricao.value + "&amp;quot; src=&amp;quot;" + urlimg.value + "&amp;quot; border=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot; " + codlarguraparse + " " + codalturaparse + "/&amp;gt;"
  caixa.innerHTML = inicio + imagem + caixacod + linkparse + imagemparse + fim;
}
</script>
<br />
<div style="clear: both;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é na pontuação. Faltou ponto-e-vírgula em alguns lugares. Sempre use ponto-e-vírgula ao terminar uma instrução. Agora funciona:

```
<span style="color: #3d85c6;">
Código do seu Gadget está abaixo!</span></h3>
<div style="text-align: center;">
<textarea name="resultado" onfocus="this.select()" onmouseover="this.focus()" style="height: 200px; margin: 2px; width: 580px;"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
var titulo       = document.getElementById("titulo");
var descricao    = document.getElementById("descricao");
var urlblog      = document.getElementById("urlblog");
var urlimg       = document.getElementById("urlimg");
var larguraimg   = document.getElementById("larguraimg");
var alturaimg    = document.getElementById("alturaimg");
var larguracaixa = document.getElementById("larguracaixa");
var alturacaixa  = document.getElementById("alturacaixa");
var botao        = document.getElementsByClassName("gerarcodigo")[0];
var caixa        = document.getElementsByName("resultado")[0];
var inicio       = "<div align=&quot;center&quot;>";
var fim          = "&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;</textarea></div>";

botao.onclick = function() {
  if (larguracaixa == "")
    {larguracaixa = 200};
  if (alturacaixa == "")
    {alturacaixa = 60};
  if (larguraimg == "")
    {codlagura = "";
     codlaguraparse = "";}
  else
    {codlargura = "width=&quot;" + larguraimg.value + "&quot;";
     codlarguraparse = "width=&amp;quot;" + larguraimg.value + "&amp;quot;";}
  if (alturaimg == "")
    {codaltura = "";
     codalturaparse = "";}
  else
    {codaltura = "height=&quot;" + alturaimg.value + "&quot;";
     codalturaparse = "height=&amp;quot;" + alturaimg.value + "&amp;quot;"}
  imagem = "<img alt=&quot;" + titulo.value + " - " + descricao.value + "&quot; title=&quot;" + titulo.value + " - " + descricao.value + "&quot; src=&quot;" + 

urlimg.value + "&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; " + codlargura + " " + codaltura + "/>";
  caixacod     = "<br/><textarea onfocus=&quot;this.select()&quot; style=&quot;margin: 2px; width: " + larguracaixa.value + "px; height: " + alturacaixa.value + 

"px&quot; onmouseover=&quot;this.focus()&quot; name=&quot;textarea&quot;>";
  linkparse    = "&amp;lt;a href=&amp;quot;" + urlblog.value + "&amp;quot; target=&amp;quot;_blank&amp;quot;&amp;gt;";
  imagemparse  = "&amp;lt;img alt=&amp;quot;" + titulo.value + " - " + descricao.value + "&amp;quot; title=&amp;quot;" + titulo.value + " - " + descricao.value + 

"&amp;quot; src=&amp;quot;" + urlimg.value + "&amp;quot; border=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot; " + codlarguraparse + " " + codalturaparse + "/&amp;gt;";
  caixa.innerHTML = inicio + imagem + caixacod + linkparse + imagemparse + fim;
}
</script>
<br />
<div style="clear: both;">
</div>
```

Comment: Carlos, eu usei o código mas não obtive sucesso. Continuo com o mesmo problema. Nada é exibido como resultado na caixa.

Comment: Então o problema deve ser em outro lugar. Testei o código usando o notepad e funcionou.